# Get data from other spreadsheet to the required cell by entering a unique ID

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, automation, google-sheets-formula

So here I am trying to automate my google sheet.

1. I have a Google sheet with 2 spreadsheets in it (i.Sheet, ii.Test_Form)
2. on the "Sheet" I have multiple data in a table (Order Date, Order Number, Status, Product, Name and etc)
3. I want to go to "Test_Form" and put my order number in a cell to get all other related data to that particular order number in the designated cells.

I don't know either this is possible or not. but I really need this :(
I appreciate the help.
[image: This is a sheet where all the required data is populated and still populating on daily bases]
[image: This is the test_form where I want to populate data according to a search query by order number]

Comment: This can be done but you have to link each cell individually to the designated cells in the test_form as the data in the sheet is not as randomized as the form hence it will need a detailed code which you can develop and post here to get it fine tuned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Harsh's comment on your post, you need to link each cell individually. And since there is a lot on your sheet and actually isn't shared, what I can only post here is a sample code that actually works testing a dummy data similar to what you posted above. You just have to fix the cell locations.

It has ample documentation so it should be readable.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  // if cell being edited is B2 of test_form sheet
  if(e.range.getColumn() == 2 && e.range.getRow() == 1 && spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getName() == "test_form") {
    // sheet containing data
    var dataSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    // sheet form
    var formSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("test_form");

    // last row of dataSheet
    var lastRow = dataSheet.getLastRow();
    // get data from A2:E, adjust to what your data needs
    var sheetData = dataSheet.getRange("A2:E" + lastRow).getValues();

    sheetData.forEach(function (row) {
      // if B1 cell value after editing is found Sheet1 1st column
      if(formSheet.getRange("B1").getValue() == row[0]){
        // set value manually into test_form
        formSheet.getRange("B2").setValue(row[1]); // copy 2nd column of matched row to B2
        formSheet.getRange("B3").setValue(row[2]); // 3rd column to B3
        formSheet.getRange("D1").setValue(row[3]); // 4th column to D1
        formSheet.getRange("D2").setValue(row[4]); // 5th column to D2
        // exit from function after finding the value
        return;
      }
    });
    // if not found, erase all data except entered value in B1
    formSheet.getRange("B2").setValue("");
    formSheet.getRange("B3").setValue("");
    formSheet.getRange("D1").setValue("");
    formSheet.getRange("D2").setValue("");
  }
}
```

**Test Cases:**

[image: sample1]

[image: sample2]

[image: sample3]

[image: sample4]

[image: sample5]

I also added a mechanism that when the `order number` is not found, it will remove the past values of other cells as well.

[image: sample6]

Comment: Excellent Work Nazia, I hope this solves the problem for Ali

Comment: Thanks @Harsh, Appreciate the kind gesture. One thing i see which OP is likely to encounter is the multiple cells that houses a single value, he might need to merge them. And I haven't considered that possible issue here. So it might be challenging for OP. That issue should be in another post I guess.

Comment: I am planing to do this all with google web services instead sheet itself.

Comment: How can do it with web. @nazia

Comment: one more thing. i tried to replicate your forms and code exactly and I am getting errors. @NaziA

Comment: @AliAhmed, you might need to share the sheet you're working. I can't make sure that it works until I have a sample working data. Also, I can only help you based on what your original post. For porting it to all google web services, you can have it on another post instead.

Comment: OK @NaziA i will make a new post and share with you